# How to delete multiple custom options?

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I want to Delete products custom options using bulk remove functionality. How I can archive that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this by custom script

```
//$products is your products collection where custom options needs to be deleted
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product = $this->productModel->load($product->getId()); //$this->productModel is the object of \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
    if ($product->getOptions()) {
        foreach ($product->getOptions() as $opt) {
            $opt->delete();
        }
        echo $product->getId()." Options deleted";
    } else {
        echo $product->getId()." has no option";
    }
}
```

You can either use it in custom script, or in admin controller, where ever you need.

Answer (score 0):

> Run Script in your magento2 root directory

```
ob_start();
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $products = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getCollection();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
        if($product->getOptions() != ”){
           foreach ($product->getOptions() as $opt){
                       $opt->delete();
                   }
           $product->setHasOptions(0)->save();
      }
    }
```